# If statements in bash not working despite being executable

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Can anyone please help, I have an if statement in my Bash code that goes as is:

```
if [[ $1 == *.txt ]]; then
  echo "It's a TXT file!!!"
fi
```

I set the shell code to executable by adding `#!/bin/sh`, and doing `chmod u+x main.sh,` but it still prints out the error:

```
./main.sh: 3: [[: not found
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This might help: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: `[[` is not part of "if" syntax even in bash; `[[` is its own command, which can be used without needing `if` at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[[` is a non-portable bashism and your shell (if it is bash) is not running as bash, but was likely invoked as `/bin/sh` or somehow forgot what `[[` is.

The way to test for this in the fully posixly portable way:

```
case $1 in
(*.txt) echo "It's a TXT file.";;
(*)     echo "You've got to be kidding me!";;
esac
```

Comment: is there a way to run a function/if statement on the line '(*.txt) echo "It's a TXT file.";;'?

Comment: @1BL1ZZARD, `echo` _is_ a statement; you can replace it with any other valid statement, including calling a function you defined.

Answer (score 2):

`[[` doesn't exist in `sh`, you need `#!/bin/bash` in the shebang line instead.